# How to stop a hover animation on click so that a new animation could be played?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried essentially everything I could find, adding and removing classes setting a timer but nothing worked

How to stop a hover animation on click so that a new animation could be played?

```js
var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');

gridItems.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.add('no-hover')
    setTimeout(function() {
      item.classList.add('transform-active');
    }, 300);
    this.classList.add('gone')
  });
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #3d499b;
  box-shadow: 5.5px 5.5px #1e286c;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.grid-item:not(.no-hover):hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  background-color: #5463cd;
}

.grid-item.transform-active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.grid-item.gone {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item" id="1"></div>
```

Comment: This code seems a bit incomplete. What "hover" animation are you trying to stop? What animation are you trying add? What the expected outcome of your code?

Comment: @disinfor Everything that needs to be there is there sorry if its not well readable, the animation I want to add is the one in the class `.grid-item.transform-active` as mentioned in the JS code when I add all the classes. The expected outcome of this operation is that the hover animation (class `.grid-item:not(.no-hover):hover`) is stopped and the `.grid-item.transform-active` animation is played. Currenrly the animation is playing but I need to hover my mouse off the element which I dont want to do since the animation is only 0.3 seconds long for efficiency

Comment: Do you want the position of the element to go back to its original position or scale from the current position in the first animation?

Comment: What is the `gone` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');

gridItems.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    item.classList.add('no-hover')
    item.classList.add('transform-active');
  });
});
```

```css
html { /* Just for display purposes */
  height: 100%;
}

body { /* Just for display purposes */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #3d499b;
  box-shadow: 5.5px 5.5px #1e286c;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.grid-item:not(.no-hover):hover {
  animation: raise 0.3s ease-in-out 0s 1;
  background-color: #5463cd;
}

.grid-item.transform-active {
  animation: embiggen 0.3s forwards;
}

@keyframes raise {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}

@keyframes embiggen {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item" id="1"></div>
```